# Why new installed laravel not work on shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Now I have installed the Laravel framework using composer command "`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myappname`" on a local server and everything works fine. Then with the same composer command installed on the shared hosting but nothing works. When I visit to index page return error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```

When I run command `php artisan` return error on cosole:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/c/cn89872/website.com/public_html/bot/ii/bootstrap/app.php:14
```

How can be solved my problem?

Comment: First `composer dump-autoload` and then `composer update --no-scripts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all run this command:`composer dump-autoload` This command will clean up all compiled files and their paths.

After `composer update --no-scripts` This command will Skips execution of scripts defined in `composer.json`

Finally, update your project's dependencies:  `composer update`